# Passing argment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have a function called token2char that is passed in an array of characters called token with an array size of 1024. I am iterating through each character, finding if it is hex (Hex value is assumed to always be 2 in length eg. 0xFF) or an integer between 0 and 255. The values are moved into a new char array `hex` and `dec` respectively, which are then passed to another function that converts it to ASCII. A truncated version of my code for hex is below.

```
void token2char(char token[1024]){
    // Iterate through each character in token
    for (int i = 0; i < maxInputLength; i = i + 1){
        // Ignore spaces, move to next char in token
        if (token[i] == ' '){}

        // Is Hex?
        else if (token[i] == '0' && (token[i+1] == 'x' || token[i+1] == 'X')){
            char hex[4];
            strcpy(hex, token[i,i+1,i+2,i+3]);
            hexConv(hex);
        }
    }
}
```

strcpy is throwing the error defined in the title, but I'm not sure why. I've tried calling &token or *token inside strcpy to no avail.

Comment: Note that `strcpy(hex, token[i,i+1,i+2,i+3]);` does not do what you think.  It is also the source of your "passing argument" error.  The code passes `token[i+3]` (a single character) to `strcpy()`, which expects a pointer to a null terminated string as the second argument.  Nominally, you might be able to use `&token[i]` as the second argument.  More likely, you should use `char hex[5]; memmove(hex, &token[i], 4); hex[4] = '\0';` to copy the data.  Note that the `i,i+1,i+2` part of the expression are ignored; search for 'comma operator' for the details of why.

Comment: Actually the code shows that you need the chapter about the arrays and pointers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler did you consider when `i = maxInputLength-1` ? Your solution may leads to UB

Comment: @kiranBiradar: No; I worked on i+3 must be in the string.  That's why it is comment, not answer.

Comment: regarding: *or decimal (###)*   The posted code does not perform this criteria!  Why would you expect a decimal number to always be 3 digits?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler indeed it works if we consider I+3

Comment: @user3629249 I clarified in the original post that my hex values are assumed to always be 2 bits 0x## in length. The decimal number is any number between 0 and 255, with 0 represented as 0, not 000, and so on.

Comment: I think you are using the word "bit" to mean "hex digit". This is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
token[i,i+1,i+2,i+3]
```

is interpreted as

```
token[i+3]
```

because the comma is an [operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

You should use

```
strncpy(hex, &token[i], 4);
```

or

```
memcpy(hex, &token[i], 4);
```

instead.

Comment: memcpy may lead to out of bound

Comment: @kiranBiradar: not more than `strncpy`. As the original code is written, we take for granted that `token[i+3]` is accessible (and contains an hex digit). And with `memcpy`, you don't have to wonder if a null will be appended.

Comment: Yes, if we consider  each hex value as single digit memcpying 4 char at time might work.

Comment: Strncpy will handle out of bound access internally memcpy doesn't.

Comment: @kiranBiradar: there is no risk of out of bound access, why worry ?

Comment: @kiranBiradar `strncpy` will not handle out of bounds accesses.

Comment: @melpomene at least for source string?

Comment: @kiranBiradar If you mean `strncpy` will stop reading from the source string when it encounters a `'\0'`, sure; but nothing in OP's code indicates that `token` is NUL-terminated.

Comment: @melpomene we usually assume strings are NULL terminated.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Why are you assuming `token` is a string? All OP said was that it's an array of chars.

Comment: @kiranBiradar: you are missing that memcpy does not rely on a null terminator, hence it is safer.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code is a long ways from compiling.  I.E. there are a lot of problems besides the incorrect parameter to `strcpy()`

The following proposed code:

1. caveat: does not handle the corner cases
2. caveat: does not handle decimal numbers
3. eliminates unnecessary copying of the data
4. cleanly compiles
5. avoids 'magic' numbers
6. modifies 'hexConv()' to return a count of how many characters were consumed
7. uses the system header file: 'ctype.h' facility 'isspace()'

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <ctype.h>

// avoid 'magic' numbers
#define MAX_INPUT_LENGTH 1024


//prototypes
void token2char( char * );
int  hexConv( char * );  // returns num of chars used


void token2char( char token[ MAX_INPUT_LENGTH ] )
{
    // Iterate through each character in token
    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_INPUT_LENGTH; i++ )
    {
        // Ignore spaces, move to next char in token
        if ( !isspace( token[i] ) )
        {
            if ( token[i] == '0' 
                && (token[i+1] == 'x' || token[i+1] == 'X') )
            {
                int charsUsed = hexConv( &token[i] );
                i += charsUsed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```